# Limit CPU Usage per client

Tags: php, apache

I have a PHP app running on a windows server with apache.

I have noticed the CPU usage sometimes going to over 30% (with Apache HHTP Server using the most). When this happens, the entire system is slowed and all the users end up getting slowed down.

I suspect one client may be running intensive queries and degrading performance for others. Is there a way to limit each client to a maximum CPU usage?

Comment: When you say `client may be running intensive queries` do you mean your clients are able to run custom queries on your server?

Comment: There are dynamic reports in the app which allow the client to make a query to be run. Some of these queries end up being heavy.

Comment: optimise your queries instead of hacking your server setup

Comment: also, if data doesn't frequently change, cache the result

Comment: Changing the queries is a long term solution. I'm trying to look for something that can work immediately.

Comment: If clients are allowed to create new queries, thinking about query optimization might not be the way to tackle the problem because programmer has not much control over what query they might create. It would be difficult to optimize a query programmatically. But I think you need to benchmark your program and make sure what the problem is. 30% CPU usage for a few seconds should not slow down the entire system. Also I think complex queries will affect the CPU usage for database management system's process not Apache. I suggest you inspect memory and I/O usage as well.

Comment: What you consider a “client”, is likely nothing the web server knows about to begin with. Such resource limitation usually rather happens on the OS user level, but I doubt your “clients” are actually represented as such. Way too little info so far for this question to even begin to become answerable with anything else but a quick “no, most likely not.”